# Convertion of multiple csv automatically to shp

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, shapefile, arcgis-10.0, csv

I have more than two hundreds similar csv files with columns (x, y, value1, value2, objectName). I need to convert them automatically to shp files with x and y columns as the coordinates.

Could you please advice how to do it using Python scripting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to iterate through every shapefile in your folder with [ListFiles](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v0000001q000000). You might use [Make XY Event Layer GP tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000006z000000) to create an event layer with the point shape (XY). Then you could use [Copy Features GP tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000035000000).

Something like:

```
import arcpy,os
shpworkspace = r"C:\GIS"
arcpy.env.workspace = shpworkspace
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

csvlist = arcpy.ListFiles("*.csv")

for csvfile in csvlist:
    outlayer = "CSVEventLayer"
    spatialreference = "GEOGCS['GCS_WGS_1984',DATUM['D_WGS_1984',SPHEROID['WGS_1984',6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]];-400 -400 1000000000;-100000 10000;-100000 10000;8.98315284119522E-09;0.001;0.001;IsHighPrecision"
    arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(csvfile,"POINT_X","POINT_Y",outlayer,spatialreference,"#")

    shpfile = os.path.splitext(csvfile)[0]        
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(outlayer,shpfile)
del outlayer
```

Here is the [.csv sample file](http://gpdemos.esri.com/demos/uploadcsv/grafiti1.csv) which you can use for getting the script to work with and then use your own data later on.